# Android service does not keep running indefinitely

Tags: android, service

I have been thinking about this question. If a service uses some references to variables of an activity in an indefinitely loop and because the service will not be killed unless you explicitly stop it, then will the activity still be killed as easy as no running service referencing some members of it after a while?
Any answer will be much appreciated.

Comment: @Onik depends on the variables that are being shared.  If the Activity itself has a reference, it isn't valid.  Same problem if a non static class is shared, as non-static classes have an implicit reference to the parent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Activity can be killed if it has other components referencing its variables-  it just may not be able to be garbage collected.  So you'll have an extra copy of the Activity around, if any of those shared variables have an explicit or implicit reference to the Activity.  This is a memory leak (yes, they are possible in Java).  This is why sharing variables between components is a bad idea.

Comment: Thanks for your quick and very reasonable answer! I will try to make my service not rely on any activity in order to run indefinitely.